# How to query and filtering XML files in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have been using Visual Studio for some time and trying learn programming in C#.

Currently, my focus is the xml structures.

In specific, I am trying to develop a simple console application that basically:

1. loads one xml file - which is the output of another program with a fairly complex structure;
2. filter the information on this xml file through certain sql-like filtering statements;
3. saving the outcome as another xml file.

The xml file I am working on is a large file with thousands of repetitive rows (that carries info about the results of a certain process). To give an idea, a shortened version of this xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OptimizationResultList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Results>
    <OptimizationResult>
      <Symbol>GARAN60</Symbol>
      <ParameterValues>
        <double>120</double>
        <double>1</double>
        <double>120</double>
        <double>1</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </ParameterValues>
      <Results>
        <double>-94926.02</double>
        <double>-3.59</double>
        <double>236</double>
        <double>32.2</double>
        <double>-0.04</double>
      </Results>
      <AverageProfitAcrossTotalTimeSpan>0</AverageProfitAcrossTotalTimeSpan>
    </OptimizationResult>
    <OptimizationResult>
      <Symbol>GARAN60</Symbol>
      <ParameterValues>
        <double>120</double>
        <double>1</double>
        <double>120</double>
        <double>2</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </ParameterValues>
      <Results>
        <double>-149389.21</double>
        <double>-5.76</double>
        <double>282</double>
        <double>33.69</double>
        <double>-0.05</double>
      </Results>
      <AverageProfitAcrossTotalTimeSpan>0</AverageProfitAcrossTotalTimeSpan>
    </OptimizationResult>
    <OptimizationResult>
      <Symbol>GARAN60</Symbol>
      <ParameterValues>
        <double>120</double>
        <double>1</double>
        <double>120</double>
        <double>3</double>
        <double>1</double>
      </ParameterValues>
      <Results>
        <double>-64926.02</double>
        <double>-5.59</double>
        <double>636</double>
        <double>42.2</double>
        <double>0.04</double>
      </Results>
      <AverageProfitAcrossTotalTimeSpan>0</AverageProfitAcrossTotalTimeSpan>
    </OptimizationResult>
  </Results>
  <Names>
    <string>Net Profit</string>
    <string>APR %</string>
    <string>Trades</string>
    <string>Winning %</string>
    <string>Avg Profit %</string>
  </Names>
  <Symbols>
    <string>GARAN60</string>
  </Symbols>
  <StrategyID>8fbc3832-7a0d-497c-bfab-a2c52dd15761</StrategyID>
  <Scorecard>MS123 Scorecard</Scorecard>
  <OptimizationMethod>Exhaustive</OptimizationMethod>
</OptimizationResultList>
```

(As you have noticed, the Results, that is the backbone of this output xml, is repeated 3 times here. The original file includes 50K+ entries in most cases.)

My question is basically this:

How do code in C# to filter this XML and return only the Results:

**1) Results>OptimizationResult>ParameterValues> the second double value of ParameterValues is between 1 and 3;**

**2) AND, Results>OptimizationResult>Results> the third double value of Results is greater than 500;**

I visited many entries in stackoverflow.com, checked in MSDN pages, but, frankly, I was not able to finalize the code that does this filtering.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Aykut Saribiyik

Comment: If you weren't able to "finalize" the code that suggests you at least made a start - why not show us what you've done already and tell us what you had trouble with? I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

basically, i resolved the issue by not improving my xml editing capabilities, but instead by simply leaning on my old good habits. Simply put, I now load all the relevant values of the relevant elements into one DataTable. After this is done, querying becomes much easier. The flip side is that, it is not cost efficient as I have to load huge set of data into the DataTable just to run a few, simple queries. Nevertheless, I pick effectiveness rather than efficiency this time. Thanks all of you for paying attention. Aykut – Aykut Saribiyik just now  edit

Comment: This doesn't feel like a good long term strategy to me. You say that querying becomes much easier, but that just suggests to me that you never quite got your head round LINQ to XML. It's really not that hard, and the benefit of not having to go back to a DataTable is immense. Why not give it another try, editing your code into the question? Then others can help you add a new string to your bow. Without that, you might as well delete this question, as it won't be of any help to anyone else.